# Turning a Mongoose seeding script into a promise

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to wrap my head around promises trying to solve a scenario I find myself in a lot of times: seeding a MongoDB database. So I got the following script which I want to turn into a Promise, preferably using ES6, but would take a bluebird as an answer if that's the case.
This is what I got using `setTimeout` to give time to the write operations before closing the database:

```js
// Importing the connection to the `bookshelf` db.
var bookshelfConn = require('./database');

// Importing the Mongoose model we'll use to write to the db.
var Book = require('./models/Book');

// Importing the Data to populate the db.
var books = require('./dataset');

// When the connection is ready, do the music!
bookshelfConn.on('open', function () {
  dropDb(seedDb, closeDb);
});

function dropDb (cb1, cb2) {
  bookshelfConn.db.dropDatabase();
  console.log('Database dropped!');
  cb1(cb2);
}

function seedDb (cb) {
  console.time('Seeding Time'); // Benchmarking the seed process.

  // Warning! Slow IO operation.
  books.forEach(function (book) {
    new Book(book).save(function (err) {
      if (err) console.log('Oopsie!', err);
    });
    console.log('Seeding:', book);
  });

  console.timeEnd('Seeding Time'); // Benchmarking the seed process.

  cb();
}

function closeDb () {
  setTimeout(function () {
    bookshelfConn.close(function () {
      console.log('Mongoose connection closed!');
    });
  }, 1000); // Delay closing connection to give enough time to seed!
}
```

Updated code to reflect zangw's answer:

```js
// Importing the connection to the `bookshelf` db.
var bookshelfConn = require('./database');

// Importing the Mongoose model we'll use to write to the db.
var Book = require('./models/Book');

// Importing the Data to populate the db.
var books = require('./dataset');

// When the connection is ready, do the music!
bookshelfConn.on('open', function () {
  // Here we'll keep an array of Promises
  var booksOps = [];

  // We drop the db as soon the connection is open
  bookshelfConn.db.dropDatabase(function () {
    console.log('Database dropped');
  });

  // Creating a Promise for each save operation
  books.forEach(function (book) {
    booksOps.push(saveBookAsync(book));
  });

  // Running all the promises sequentially, and THEN
  // closing the database.
  Promise.all(booksOps).then(function () {
    bookshelfConn.close(function () {
      console.log('Mongoose connection closed!');
    });
  });

  // This function returns a Promise.
  function saveBookAsync (book) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
      new Book(book).save(function (err) {
        if (err) reject(err);
        else resolve();
      });
    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try to do it through [`new Promise`](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/new-promise.html) and [`Promise.all`](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.all.html)

`new Promise` to create a new promise. The passed in function will receive functions resolve and reject as its arguments which can be called to seal the fate of the created promise.

`Promise.all` is useful for when you want to wait for more than one promise to complete.

```
var bookOps = [];

books.forEach(function (book) {
    bookOps.push(saveBookAsync(book));
});

Promise.all(bookOps).then(function() {
   bookshelfConn.close(function () {
      console.log('Mongoose connection closed!');
    });
});

function saveBookAsync(book) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        new Book(book).save(function(err) {
            if (err)
                reject(err);
            else
                resolve();
        })
    });
}
```

Comment: thanks it works flawlessly. I didn't know about `Promise.all` at all ))