# What is wrong with seeder file and mongoose settings that I just can't save my seeder models?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

Here is my Seeder file

```js
var Product = require('../models/product.js');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/cart', { useMongoClient: true });

mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
mongoose.connection.once('connected', function() {
    console.log("Database connected successfully")
});

var products = [

    new Product({

        title: 'SuperMan Toy',
        description: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quasi totam praesentium commodi! Minima fugiat error possimus at ea quaerat a sit repudiandae laudantium. Ducimus quibusdam, assumenda iusto, doloribus quod debitis.',
        price: 550,
        imgPath: '#'

    }),
    new Product({

        title: 'Batman Toy',
        description: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quasi totam praesentium commodi! Minima fugiat error possimus at ea quaerat a sit repudiandae laudantium. Ducimus quibusdam, assumenda iusto, doloribus quod debitis.',
        price: 450,
        imgPath: '#'

    }),

    new Product({

        title: 'Hulk Toy',
        description: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quasi totam praesentium commodi! Minima fugiat error possimus at ea quaerat a sit repudiandae laudantium. Ducimus quibusdam, assumenda iusto, doloribus quod debitis.',
        price: 650,
        imgPath: '#'

    }),
];

var done = 0;

for (i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {

    products[i].save(function(err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log('Not Saved')
        }
    });

    done++;

    if (done === products.length) {
        mongoose.disconnect();
    }
}
```

you can check whole template at https://github.com/oaulakh/nodejs_testing

https://github.com/oaulakh/nodejs_testing/blob/master/seeder/productSeeder.js

I'm doing something wrong here, if yes how I can fix this so my mongo start saving my models?

Comment: Add a callback to the disconnect function where you add `console.log('closing db connection')`, to determine if you're closing the database before the documents have been saved. Might be the case because save is async. So the connection is pretty much closed instantly. You can convert the routine into using promises (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35662618/turning-a-mongoose-seeding-script-into-a-promise)) or use `mongoimport` instead.

Comment: yeah its running fine but still i just cant figure out what the problem with mongoose